# Android dragging imageView after rotating it

Tags: android, rotation, image-rotation

I don't know how to solve a problem, I have created an application where I can drag objects on the screen, I can rotate them and keep dragging them. I am moving the objects using margins, left and top. The main issue with the application is that when I try to check collisions (because I don't want that object to overlap) the object is seen. How I created it (horizontal only ) because I create them horizontal and rotate them vertical.
So the shape of the object still remains horizontal after rotating the image vertical, how can I change this ?

Comment: Ok after 1 hour of hard thinking, my other question is if I can create a function that will return a new imageview as parameter ? I am thinking to replace the old imageview with a new one when rotating it.